# PHP inserting string issue

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to add CSS class 'is-icon-pdf' to PHP string.

- I'm tring to modify WordPress gutenberg block dynamically.

```
$before1 = '<div class="wp-block-button"><a class="wp-block-button__link">button</a></div>';
$before2 = '<div class="wp-block-button is-style-button-large"><a class="wp-block-button__link">button</a></div>';
$before3 = '<div class="wp-block-button is-style-button-large has-custom-width"><a class="wp-block-button__link">button</a></div>';
```

Results that I want.
I don't mind the position of "is-icon-pdf".It can be placed after is-style-button-large for example.

```
$after1 = '<div class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf"><a class="wp-block-button__link">button</a></div>';
$after2 = '<div class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf is-style-button-large"><a class="wp-block-button__link">button</a></div>';
$after3 = '<div class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf is-style-button-large has-custom-width"><a class="wp-block-button__link">button</a></div>';
```

What I tried.

```
str_replace( 'wp-block-button ', 'wp-block-button is-icon-pdf ', $before1 );
str_replace( 'wp-block-button ', 'wp-block-button is-icon-pdf ', $before2 );
str_replace( 'wp-block-button ', 'wp-block-button is-icon-pdf ', $before3 );
```

Following are the results I got.

```
$after1 = '<div class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf"><a class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf__link">button</a></div>';
$after1 = '<div class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf is-style-button-large"><a class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf__link">button</a></div>';
$after1 = '<div class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf is-style-button-large has-custom-width"><a class="wp-block-button is-icon-pdf__link">button</a></div>';
```

a class = "wp-block-button__link" part should be left unchanged.
Hope someone help me with this.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explanation but I'm afraid WordPress core could add another class before 'wp-block-button'.
I'll try to find about preg_replace. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely is just a starting point for you as the regex may be fine tuned for your data.  This uses [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$after = preg_replace('/(<div.*?class=".*?(?<=[ "])wp-block-button(?=[ "]))(.*?")/', '$1 is-icon-pdf $2', $before);
```

The regex specifies:

> match all `div` elements with a `class` list which includes `wp-block-button` and replace the class list entry with `wp-block-button is-icon-pdf`.

A good sandbox site is http::phpyliveregex.com#tab-preg-replace and this example with a few more tests can be found here:

[Test Sandbox](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/DlH#tab-preg-replace)

Comment: Your preg_replace code worked fine! Your sandbox will also help me to learn more.